# iphone app approval question

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

Anybody has any experience getting an *app* that uses web services approved ?

I'm planning to create an *app* that will send an e-mail to an address selected from the address book.

I was thinking to send the contact's email address to the web service and then generate the message from there.

**1.** Will I be required to use *https* (*SSL*) to accomplish this?
 **2.** Do I need to have some kind of a disclosure about how the e-mail address will be used?

Thank you

Laz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the user is selecting the address, it shouldn't cause issue in app store. However, the user might not like the fact that the address is being sent to some server without their approval and leave negative feedback.

Either add a disclosure somewhere or inform the user via some alert before continuing communication with the server.

Comment: I did more research and looks like addition to the disclosure I need to deal with some paperwork because of the https

Comment: Not sure what you mean about paperwork for https. I have an app which connects to a server via https to use some SOAP webservice but that is not an issue when submitting the app.

Comment: According to this blog
http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html

you have to have an ERN if you use https?

Comment: Upvote to your question for providing this info. Learnt something new today. I had submitted an app which uses https to connect to a server but didn't mark that the app uses encryption when submitting it to app store. The app got approved so never ran into this issue. Will need to check it out further.